# how to call a string type method?

Tags: java

how to call this method in the main method?
I'm not able to call my user-defined method in the main method. How to do it?

```
public class Concat {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


    }

    public static String UserInfo (String name, String email, String address) { 
        name="vgfhk";
        email="dbdkjb";
        address="jbkug";
        String code="Thanks for running the code\n\n";
        String below="Your information is given below:\n";

        String thanksMsg = "Hello, "+name+code+below;

        String userInformation="Name: "+name+"email: "+email+"Address: "+address;

        return thanksMsg.concat(userInformation);   
    } 
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: Why aren't you able to call that method? What problems do you run into? Note that you're reassigning the parameters, e.g. `name="Farhan";` will make the method use that name and ignore whatever you've passed. I assume that's not what you want so remove the first 3 lines of that method and call it like `UserInfo("Farhan", "dbdkjb", "mirpur")` - and btw, `UserInfo()` looks a lot like a constructor which might cause confusion. Thus the code conventions state that the method should start with a lower case character, e.g. `userInfo(...)`.

Comment: Stick to the Java naming conventions and make the method name start with a lower case `u`. Then remove the hard coded redefinition of the arguments (the first three lines in the method body) and call the method in `main` like `System.out.println(userInfo("Farhan", "dbdkjb", "mirpur"));`.

Comment: Just a hint: By conventions, java method names start with a lowercase letter. It doesn't effect the functionality but shared conventions *really* help making the code clear.

Comment: and you can call the method by executing `UserInfo("Farhan","dbdkjb","mirpur")`. In that case, the lines 
`name="Farhan";
email="dbdkjb";
address="mirpur";`
are redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call the function as you have defined it as static.
I have passed input values as Null which you can replace as you need.

```
public class Concat {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String result = userInfo(null, null, null);

    }

    public static String userInfo (String name, String email, String address) { 
        name="Farhan";
        email="dbdkjb";
        address="mirpur";
        String code="Thanks for running the code\n\n";
        String below="Your information is given below:\n";

        String thanksMsg = "Hello, "+name+code+below;

        String userInformation="Name: "+name+"email: "+email+"Address: "+address;

        return thanksMsg.concat(userInformation);   
    } 
}
```

**NOTE**  : Your method name doesn't follow java coding conventions. You should follow Oracle guidelines around it. https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: It's not that the method *must* follow the code conventions but it *should*...

Answer (score 0):

Almost there.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String result = giveUserInfo("Farhan", "db@dk.jb", "mirpur");
    System.out.println(result);     |
}                                   +-------+
                                            |
private static String giveUserInfo (String name, String email, String address) { 
    String code="Thanks for running the code\n\n";
    String below="Your information is given below:\n";

    String thanksMsg = "Hello, "+name+code+below;

    String userInformation="Name: "+name+"email: "+email+"Address: "+address;

    return thanksMsg + userInformation;   
}
```

The convention being method and variable names in java beginning with a small letter.